# Is it possible to use async_trait with dynamic dispatch

Tags: rust, traits, rust-tokio

I am trying to create a async_trait that use a dyn reference to Iterator.

Here is an example of my code :

```
#[async_trait::async_trait]
trait StringPrinter { 
    async fn print(a: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = String>); 
}

struct MyStringPrinter{} 

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl StringPrinter for MyStringPrinter { 
    async fn print(a: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = String>){
       a.for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));     
       tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await; 
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains on : `future created by async block is not 'Send'`

On the other hand - simple version of async function works well:

```
async fn print_iterator(a: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = String>) { 
    a.for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));     
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await; 
}
```

Any idea what is different ? or any idea for workaround?

Comment: Also, `async_trait` requires `Send` by default, but if that's not actually desired then you can customize the attribute to make it optional: `#[async_trait::async_trait(?Send)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, after all the `#[async_trait]` proc-macro rewrites the method to use a boxed future. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/async-trait/0.1.51/async_trait/index.html#explanation) of the crate:

> Async fns get transformed into methods that return `Pin<Box<dyn Future + Send + 'async>>` and delegate to a private `async` freestanding function.

But generated future will be `Send` if and only if all its members implement `Send`. Yet your iterator does not:

```rust
&mut dyn Iterator<Item = String>
```

Just change that to:

```rust
&mut (dyn Iterator<Item = String> + Send)
```

Comment: thanks ! so I realized that my real problem was to understand the syntax to add the Send tait :) , before i asked the question i tries some version  and none of them compile ..